# captureOutput:didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:fromConnections:error not being called

Tags: ios, avcapturesession, avcam

I am writing a videocapture app for ios 4+. It works fine on devices with ios 5+ but in ios 4+ the delegate didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL is not being called after the recording has stopped. I have checked apple's reference which says "This method is always called for each recording request, even if no data is successfully written to the file."

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Any suggestions ?

Here is the complete code:

/

```
/
//  HomeViewController.m
//  MyAgingBooth
//
//  Created by Mahmud on 29/10/11.
//  Copyright 2011 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "HomeViewController.h"
#import "Globals.h"
#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MPMoviePlayerController.h>
#import "SharedData.h"
#import "ResultViewController.h"

@implementation HomeViewController

@synthesize BtnFromCamera, PreviewLayer;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization


        isPlaying=NO;
        playerScore=0;
        playerTurn=0;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    //[levelTimer release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent; 
    playerName.text=[NSString stringWithFormat: @"Player %d", (playerTurn+1)];
    //add a right bar button item proceed to next.
    UIBarButtonItem *proceedButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Proceed" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(proceedToNext)];
    //[proceedButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"info.png"]];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=proceedButton;
    [proceedButton release];
    [BtnFromCamera setTitle:@"Start" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    //[self.BtnFromCamera setImage:camera forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    //[self.BtnFromCamera setImage:camera forState:UIControlStateSelected];

    NSArray *words=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"SAY: Girls",@"SAY: Shut up", @"SAY: Tiger",@"SAY: Absurd",@"SAY: Tonight", @"SAY: Amstardam", nil];
    [word setText:[words objectAtIndex:arc4random()%6]];


    [self initCaptureSession];
}

-(void) proceedToNext
{
    self.title=@"Back";
    ResultViewController *resultViewController= [[ResultViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ResultViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:resultViewController animated:YES];
    [resultViewController release];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

//Action handlers for the buttons

// take snap with camera

-(void) initCaptureSession
{
    NSLog(@"Setting up capture session");
    CaptureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];

    //----- ADD INPUTS -----
    NSLog(@"Adding video input");

    //ADD VIDEO INPUT
    AVCaptureDevice *VideoDevice =  [self frontFacingCameraIfAvailable ];

    //[AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    if (VideoDevice)
    {
        NSError *error;
        VideoInputDevice = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:VideoDevice error:&error];
        if (!error)
        {
            if ([CaptureSession canAddInput:VideoInputDevice])
                [CaptureSession addInput:VideoInputDevice];
            else
                NSLog(@"Couldn't add video input");
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Couldn't create video input");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Couldn't create video capture device");
    }

    //ADD AUDIO INPUT
    NSLog(@"Adding audio input");
    AVCaptureDevice *audioCaptureDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
    NSError *error = nil;
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *audioInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:audioCaptureDevice error:&error];
    if (audioInput)
    {
        [CaptureSession addInput:audioInput];
    }

    //----- ADD OUTPUTS -----

    //ADD VIDEO PREVIEW LAYER
    NSLog(@"Adding video preview layer");
    [self setPreviewLayer:[[[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:CaptureSession] autorelease]];

    PreviewLayer.orientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait;       //<<SET ORIENTATION.  You can deliberatly set this wrong to flip the image and may actually need to set it wrong to get the right image

    [[self PreviewLayer] setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];

    //ADD MOVIE FILE OUTPUT
    NSLog(@"Adding movie file output");
    MovieFileOutput = [[AVCaptureMovieFileOutput alloc] init];

    Float64 TotalSeconds = 60;          //Total seconds
    int32_t preferredTimeScale = 30;    //Frames per second
    CMTime maxDuration = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(TotalSeconds, preferredTimeScale);   //<<SET MAX DURATION
    MovieFileOutput.maxRecordedDuration = maxDuration;

    MovieFileOutput.minFreeDiskSpaceLimit = 1024 * 1024;    //<<SET MIN FREE SPACE IN BYTES FOR RECORDING TO CONTINUE ON A VOLUME



    if ([CaptureSession canAddOutput:MovieFileOutput])
        [CaptureSession addOutput:MovieFileOutput];

    AudioOutput = [[AVCaptureAudioDataOutput alloc] init];
    if([CaptureSession canAddOutput:AudioOutput])
    {
        [CaptureSession addOutput:AudioOutput];
        NSLog(@"AudioOutput addedd");
    }

    //SET THE CONNECTION PROPERTIES (output properties)
    [self CameraSetOutputProperties];           //(We call a method as it also has to be done after changing camera)

    //----- SET THE IMAGE QUALITY / RESOLUTION -----
    //Options:
    //  AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh - Highest recording quality (varies per device)
    //  AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium - Suitable for WiFi sharing (actual values may change)
    //  AVCaptureSessionPresetLow - Suitable for 3G sharing (actual values may change)
    //  AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480 - 640x480 VGA (check its supported before setting it)
    //  AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720 - 1280x720 720p HD (check its supported before setting it)
    //  AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto - Full photo resolution (not supported for video output)
    NSLog(@"Setting image quality");
    [CaptureSession setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium];
    if ([CaptureSession canSetSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480])     //Check size based configs are supported before setting them
        [CaptureSession setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480];

    //----- DISPLAY THE PREVIEW LAYER -----
    //Display it full screen under out view controller existing controls
    NSLog(@"Display the preview layer");
    CGRect layerRect = CGRectMake(10,44,300,290); //[[[self view] layer] bounds];
    [PreviewLayer setBounds:layerRect];
    [PreviewLayer setPosition:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(layerRect),
                                          CGRectGetMidY(layerRect))];
    //[[[self view] layer] addSublayer:[[self CaptureManager] previewLayer]];
    //We use this instead so it goes on a layer behind our UI controls (avoids us having to manually bring each control to the front):
    UIView *CameraView = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];
    [[self view] addSubview:CameraView];
    //[self.view sendSubviewToBack:CameraView];

    [[CameraView layer] addSublayer:PreviewLayer];

    //----- START THE CAPTURE SESSION RUNNING -----
    [CaptureSession startRunning];    
}

//********** CAMERA SET OUTPUT PROPERTIES **********
- (void) CameraSetOutputProperties
{
    AVCaptureConnection *CaptureConnection=nil;
    //SET THE CONNECTION PROPERTIES (output properties)
    NSComparisonResult order = [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion compare: @"5.0.0" options: NSNumericSearch];
    if (order == NSOrderedSame || order == NSOrderedDescending) {
        // OS version >= 5.0.0
        CaptureConnection = [MovieFileOutput connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
        if (CaptureConnection.supportsVideoMinFrameDuration)
            CaptureConnection.videoMinFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, CAPTURE_FRAMES_PER_SECOND);
        if (CaptureConnection.supportsVideoMaxFrameDuration)
            CaptureConnection.videoMaxFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, CAPTURE_FRAMES_PER_SECOND);
        if (CaptureConnection.supportsVideoMinFrameDuration)
        {
            CMTimeShow(CaptureConnection.videoMinFrameDuration);
            CMTimeShow(CaptureConnection.videoMaxFrameDuration);
        }
    } else {
        // OS version < 5.0.0
            CaptureConnection = [self connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo fromConnections:[MovieFileOutput connections]];

    }



    //Set landscape (if required)
    if ([CaptureConnection isVideoOrientationSupported])
    {
        AVCaptureVideoOrientation orientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeRight;        //<<<<<SET VIDEO ORIENTATION IF LANDSCAPE
        [CaptureConnection setVideoOrientation:orientation];
    }

    //Set frame rate (if requried)
    //CMTimeShow(CaptureConnection.videoMinFrameDuration);
    //CMTimeShow(CaptureConnection.videoMaxFrameDuration);


}
- (IBAction) StartVideo
{
    if (!isPlaying) {

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled=NO;
        [BtnFromCamera setTitle:@"Stop" forState:UIControlStateNormal];  
        playerName.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Player %d", playerTurn+1];
        playerScore=0;
        count=0;
        isPlaying=YES;


    //Create temporary URL to record to
    NSString *outputPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@%@", NSTemporaryDirectory(), @"output.mov"];
    NSURL *outputURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:outputPath];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:outputPath])
    {
        NSError *error;
        if ([fileManager removeItemAtPath:outputPath error:&error] == NO)
        {
            //Error - handle if requried
            NSLog(@"file remove error");
        }
    }
    [outputPath release];
    //Start recording
    [MovieFileOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:outputURL recordingDelegate:self];
    [outputURL release];

        //NSString *DestFilename = @ "output.mov";

        //Set the file save to URL
      /*  NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss"];
        NSString *destinationPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingFormat:@"/output_%@.mov", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];
        [dateFormatter release];


        NSURL* saveLocationURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:destinationPath];
        [MovieFileOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:saveLocationURL recordingDelegate:self];
        [saveLocationURL release];        */

    levelTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target: self selector: @selector(levelTimerCallback:) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
    }
    else
    {
        isPlaying=NO;
        NSLog(@"STOP RECORDING");
        [MovieFileOutput stopRecording];
        [levelTimer invalidate];
        [BtnFromCamera setTitle:@"Start" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled=YES;
    }
}

//********** DID FINISH RECORDING TO OUTPUT FILE AT URL **********/
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureFileOutput *)captureOutput
didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:(NSURL *)outputFileURL
      fromConnections:(NSArray *)connections
                error:(NSError *)error
{

    NSLog(@"didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL - enter");

    BOOL RecordedSuccessfully = YES;
    if ([error code] != noErr)
    {
        // A problem occurred: Find out if the recording was successful.
        id value = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:AVErrorRecordingSuccessfullyFinishedKey];
        if (value)
        {
            RecordedSuccessfully = [value boolValue];
        }
    }
    if (RecordedSuccessfully)
    {
        //----- RECORDED SUCESSFULLY -----
        NSLog(@"didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL - success");
        ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
        if ([library videoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum:outputFileURL])
        {
            [library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:outputFileURL
                                        completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error)
             {
                 if (error)
                 {
                     NSLog(@"File save error");
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     playerScore=(playerScore/count);
                     NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:playerName.text, @"PlayerName", [NSNumber numberWithFloat:playerScore], @"Score", assetURL, @"VideoURL",nil];
                     SharedData *d=[SharedData sharedManager];
                     [d.PlayerStats addObject:dict];

                     [dict release];
                     playerName.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score %f", playerScore];
                     playerTurn++;
                 }
             }];
        }
        else {

            NSString *assetURL=[self copyFileToDocuments:outputFileURL];
            if(assetURL!=nil)
            {
                playerScore=(playerScore/count);
                NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:playerName.text, @"PlayerName", [NSNumber numberWithFloat:playerScore], @"Score",assetURL , @"VideoURL",nil];
                SharedData *d=[SharedData sharedManager];
                [d.PlayerStats addObject:dict];

                [dict release];
                playerName.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score %f", playerScore];
                playerTurn++;
            }
        }


        [library release];      
    }
}

- (NSString*) copyFileToDocuments:(NSURL *)fileURL
{
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss"];
    NSString *destinationPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingFormat:@"/output_%@.mov", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];
    [dateFormatter release];
    NSError *error;
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtURL:fileURL toURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:destinationPath] error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"File save error %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        return nil;

    }
    return destinationPath;
}

- (void)levelTimerCallback:(NSTimer *)timer {

    AVCaptureConnection *audioConnection = [self connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio fromConnections:[MovieFileOutput connections]];
    //return [audioConnection isActive];
    for (AVCaptureAudioChannel *channel in audioConnection.audioChannels) {
        float avg = channel.averagePowerLevel;
       // float peak = channel.peakHoldLevel;
        float vol=powf(10, avg)*1000;
        NSLog(@"Power: %f",vol);
        if (isPlaying && vol > 0) {
            playerScore=playerScore+vol;
            count=count+1;
        }
    }       
}

- (AVCaptureConnection *)connectionWithMediaType:(NSString *)mediaType fromConnections:(NSArray *)connections
{
    for ( AVCaptureConnection *connection in connections ) {
        for ( AVCaptureInputPort *port in [connection inputPorts] ) {
            if ( [[port mediaType] isEqual:mediaType] ) {
                return connection;
            }
        }
    }
    return nil;
}



- (AVCaptureDevice *)frontFacingCameraIfAvailable
{
    //  look at all the video devices and get the first one that's on the front
    NSArray *videoDevices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    AVCaptureDevice *captureDevice = nil;
    for (AVCaptureDevice *device in videoDevices)
    {
        if (device.position == AVCaptureDevicePositionFront)
        {
            captureDevice = device;
            break;
        }
    }

    //  couldn't find one on the front, so just get the default video device.
    if ( ! captureDevice)
    {
        captureDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    }

    return captureDevice;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue. I accedentally added an extra audio output. Removing the following fragment works for me.

```
AudioOutput = [[AVCaptureAudioDataOutput alloc] init];
if([CaptureSession canAddOutput:AudioOutput])
{
    [CaptureSession addOutput:AudioOutput];
    NSLog(@"AudioOutput addedd");
}
```